# Unable to silence mongoDB connection logs from log4j2 xml properties

Tags: java, kotlin, log4j2, slf4j, ktor

I am trying to disable the mongodb connection logs on my application but not able to do it with the below configuration in log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.mongodb.driver" level="OFF"/>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Application is ktor server application
Dependecies used for loggers are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.5'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.19.0'
}
```

Comment: What's an example of an unwanted message?

Comment: @tgdavies sharing an example
```[MaintenanceTimer-4-thread-1] INFO org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:25, serverValue:57547}]
```